# How to print ticks and backticks in mathmode

Tags: math-mode

How can I print ticks and backticks in math mode? I want to get something like

`` x+1 ´´

However everything I tried so far does not compile or produces other characters like "  or '

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What do you mean by “backtick”?

Comment: A single grave accent. In Computer science (which is my background) this is usually called backtick. Since I am not a native english speaker I was not aware that this is not the "official" name. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand, you are seeking  `\backprime`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\[
{}^{\backprime\backprime}{x+1}''
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good guess, I believe; but I can't understand what the meaning of this would be.

Comment: @egreg It may be some combinatorics usage. I hope OP will give a suggestion.

Comment: My guess is that it's for what people usually denote by `\ulcorner...\urcorner`

Comment: Yes, this produces the Output I was looking for.
@egreg This has no direct mathematic meaning. It is the way an extension to the Clam proof planner, I am writing about, outputs special formulas.